# LoadLibrary fails to load C++ CLI created dll

Tags: c++-cli

I created a c++/cli dll in visual studio 2010 with CLR option as shown below and created email.dll. Then to test this out created another vs2010 win32 project and tried to load the email.dll using LoadLibrary which is alwyas returning NULL:

`HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)"pathto\\email.dll");`

My question is : Should the email.dll be loaded in some other way ? or if the email.dll is created in-correctly.

C++/CLI code for email.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <system.dll>
include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;

using namespace System::Net::Mail;


extern int CallSendEmailFromGmail(char* fromEmail, char* password, char* toEmail, char* subject, char* message);


extern "C"
{
     __declspec(dllexport) int SendEmailFromGmail(char* fromEmail, char* password, char* toEmail,    char* subject, char* message)
    {
        return CallSendEmailFromGmail(fromEmail, password, toEmail, subject, message);
    }

}

int CallSendEmailFromGmail(char* fromEmail, char* password, char* toEmail, char* subject, char* message)
{

        String ^from = gcnew String(fromEmail); 
        String ^pwd = gcnew String(password);
        String ^to = gcnew String(toEmail);
        String ^subjectStr = gcnew String(subject);
        String ^messageStr = gcnew String(message);
        SmtpClient ^client = gcnew SmtpClient();
//    client->DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

      client->UseDefaultCredentials = false;
      client->Credentials = gcnew System::Net::NetworkCredential(from, pwd);
      client->Port = 587;
      client->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
      client->EnableSsl = true;
      MailMessage ^mail = gcnew MailMessage(from, to);
      mail->Subject = subjectStr;
      mail->Body = messageStr;
      try
       {
           client->Send(mail);
       }
       catch (Exception ^ex)
       {
           Console::WriteLine("Message : " + ex->Message);
           return 1;
        }

        Console::WriteLine("Message : Done" );
        return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You'll need to get out of the habit of using a cast to make the compiler stop telling you that you did it wrong.  (LPCWSTR) only stops the compiler from complaining, it didn't stop you from doing it wrong.  You prefix a string literal with L to make it a wide string, like L"This is a wide string".  Using LoadLibrary() is wrong as well, you use Assembly::LoadFrom() to load a managed assembly.  There is very little point to it, just add a reference to the assembly so the CLR will load the DLL automatically for you.

Comment: @HansPassant He's testing his exported function entry point.

Answer (score 2):

When a Win32 API function fails it usually sets an error code for the thread. So, saying that the function returns NULL isn't saying enough. The [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs point you to the [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs.

This is probably what's wrong:

```
LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)"pathto\\email.dll");
```

You can't cast to change the string's representation of a file path. You seem to have UNICODE defined, which is fine; You'll end up calling LoadLibraryW instead of LoadLibraryA. To construct a file path for LoadLibraryW, use:

```
LoadLibraryW(L"pathto\\email.dll");
```

Comment: Agreed; Thanks. Ideally, we would use `u"pathto\\email.dll"` since that's exactly what LoadLibraryW requires. But that's not supported today.

Comment: Thanks Very much it worked for me! I am able to now invoke the exported function with one change in email.dll that is surrounding the dllMain with #pragma unmanaged and #pragma managed as the testing project is built w/o clr.